# How do I convert an Oracle Date object/Long into a javascript date?

Tags: javascript, database, oracle

I'm querying a web service that returns a date from an Oracle database that looks like this: 
       `/Date(1369519200000)/`
but I haven't the slightest clue what the value of this Long represents, so I don't know how to convert it into a javascript date object.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an epoch data in milliseconds:

```
var ms = 1369519200000;
var d = new Date(0);
d.setMilliseconds(ms);
```

`d` is now 'Sat May 25 2013 22:00:00 GMT' (via `d.toUTCString()`), which hopefully sounds about what you might expect.

This doesn't take timezones into account; if you know the date is UTC you can use `setUTCMilliseconds` instead, or just:

```
var d = new Date(ms);
```

But you probably need to know exactly what the web service is sending you so you know you're interpreting the date correctly - whether you need to apply timezone or daylight saving adjustments, for example.

No idea about it's general reliability, but [this article](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Javascript_Dates-The_Complete_Reference) includes some info on data handling, including what the epoch date means.

Comment: how sure are you that this is a millisecond value?
because I've looked at other posts that explain a millisecond conversion and they have values way shorter than this, ie: int values

Comment: @pythonian29033 - I'm fairly sure just because it ends in `000` and is long enough, and as sure as I can be without seeing the raw data in the database, because when I treat it as one it converts to what looks like a sensible date. Maybe the posts you looked at used a different epoch, or started with seconds and multiplied by 1000 to get milliseconds (which I've seen in Unix-land). Doesn't the web service define what it's sending at all?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's in number of milliseconds since the UNIX *epoch* (midnight 1970).

If you can get that value as an integer you could do something like this:

```
var dbDate = new Date(0);  // start out at  time 0, i.e. the unix epoch
dbDate.setUTCSeconds(millisSinceEpoch/1000);
```